# Scrapy, Selenium, Python - problem with pagination (missing pages)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I have a problem with running scrapy. Seems like scrapy is skiping last pages. For example I've set 20 pages to scrap but Scrapy is missing last 10 or 7 pages. It does not have any problem when Im setting one single page "for page in range(6,7)". Terminal shows that it is scraping all pages from 1 to 100 but output in my database is ending at random pages. Any ideas why is that heppening?

Mayber there is a way to run Scrapy synchronously. To scrap every item in first page -> second page -> third page and so on

```
class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'default'
    urls = [f'https://www.somewebsite.com/pl/c/cat?page={page}' for page in range(1, 101)]

    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
    options.add_argument("--enable-crash-reporter")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
    options.add_argument("--incognito")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        for videos in response.css('div.card-img'):
            item = WebsitescrapperItem()
            
            link = f'https://www.somewebsite.com{videos.css("a.item-link").attrib["href"]}'
            SomeSpider.driver.get(link)
            domain_name = SomeSpider.driver.current_url
            SomeSpider.driver.back()

            item['name'] = videos.css('span.title::text').get().strip()
            item['duration'] = videos.css('span.duration::text').get().strip()
            item['image'] = videos.css('img.thumb::attr(src)').get()
            item['url'] = domain_name
            item['hd'] = videos.css('span.hd-icon').get()

            yield item
```

Comment: Hey @bryjax

It is helpful for anyone to answer your queries regarding scrapy that you share 
1. The website you are trying to scrape. 
2. Share the exact error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the code using this format of calling,

```
def parse(self, response):
    # do some stuff
    for page in range(self.total_pages):
        yield Requests(f'https://example.com/search?page={page}', 
                          callback=self.parse)
```

Also, If you yield multiple requests from start_requests, or have multiple URLs in start_urls, those will be handled asynchronously, according to your concurrency settings (Scrapy’s default is 8 concurrent requests per domain, 16 total). Make sure you set accordingly in `settings.py.`

```
# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it synchronously you would do it like so.

```
def parse(self, response, current_page):
    url = 'https://www.somewebsite.com/pl/c/cat?page={}'
    # do some stuff
    self.current_page += 1
    yield Request(url.format(current_page), call_back=self.parse)
```